# Can't get username from function login

Tags: python, flask, ldap

I'am new to python and start coding as well.
I'am setting a login() function that returns a token so i can use jtw.
My problem is that i can't seem to find a way to structure the code so i can get the value user to insert into my  `access_token = create_access_token(identity=user)`

```
def login():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.form['user']
        passwd = request.form['passwd']
        test = ldap.bind_user(user, passwd)

        if test is None or passwd == '':
            return 'Invalid credentials'
        else:
            session['user_id'] = request.form['user']
            return redirect('/index')

    access_token = create_access_token(identity=user)
    return jsonify(access_token=access_token), 200
```

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required
def index():
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    return jsonify(logged_in_as=current_user), 200
```

I should get: `"logged_in_as": user`
when i run: `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS" http://localhost:5000/index`

instead i get `logged_in_as": null`
because i can't use my identity user on my code.
It says unsolved reference

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.
I had code that was not nedded and was causing conflit.
I dind't need to check again for the post method as the route method was post already, and i dind't need the else statement.